# Can't perform Kerberos login

Tags: linux, login, pam, kerberos, apacheds

I can't do a Kerberos login.

I've tweaked `rsyslog` to record `*.debug` to `/var/log/debug`, whose output is below.

If I attempt to log in with `ssh`, I get:

```
Jun  6 23:13:05 foo-machine sshd[13965]: Invalid user roy from 204.28.116.34
Jun  6 23:13:05 foo-machine sshd[13965]: input_userauth_request: invalid user roy [preauth]
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: entry (nonull)
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): (user roy) attempting authentication as roy@EXAMPLE.COM
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): (user roy) krb5_get_init_creds_password: Decrypt integrity check failed
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname=roy uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=204.28.116.34
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: exit (failure)
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=204.28.116.34
Jun  6 23:13:06 foo-machine sshd[13965]: Libgcrypt warning: missing initialization - please fix the application
Jun  6 23:13:07 foo-machine sshd[13965]: Failed password for invalid user roy from 204.28.116.34 port 30760 ssh2
```

(Note that I'm well aware that "Decrypt integrity check failed" means "incorrect password". The password that I have supplied *is* correct.)

If I attempt to log in with `login`, I get:

```
Jun  6 22:55:58 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: entry
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:auth): (user roy) attempting authentication as roy@EXAMPLE.COM
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:auth): user roy authenticated as roy@EXAMPLE.COM
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:auth): (user roy) temporarily storing credentials in /tmp/krb5cc_pam_98AyqH
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: exit (success)
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: Libgcrypt warning: missing initialization - please fix the application
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:account): pam_sm_acct_mgmt: entry
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:account): (user roy) retrieving principal from cache
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:account): pam_sm_acct_mgmt: exit (success)
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_mail(login:session): user unknown
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_umask(login:session): account for roy not found
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_krb5(login:session): (user roy) getpwnam failed for roy
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user roy by root(uid=0)
Jun  6 22:56:00 foo-machine login[13003]: User not known to the underlying authentication module
```

If I attempt to authenticate with `kinit`, all goes well:

```
# kinit -V roy@EXAMPLE.COM
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: roy@EXAMPLE.COM
Password for roy@EXAMPLE.COM:
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
#
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-account`:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000 debug
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Note that I made a modification here; `account ... pam_krb5` was perviously in
the "Additional block", but given that `pam_deny` is set to `requisite`, it
wasn't clear to me how `pam_krb5` could ever be reached. Thus, I moved it up.
The next two files are untouched by me:

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=4 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000 debug
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=validate use_first_pass
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=update
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=store
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required                        pam_permit.so
# The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system default in
# /etc/login.defs and user settings, solving the problem of different
# umask settings with different shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.
# See "man pam_umask".
session optional                        pam_umask.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
session required        pam_unix.so
session optional        pam_systemd.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

As a minor side note, Apache DS is my LDAP and KDC server. (`/etc/krb5.conf` points to it.) (As OpenLDAP/"normal" Kerberos proved *impossible* to set up; Apache has been easier, but alas, it still doesn't work.)

**Why can't I log in?**

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have a very similar problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166135/cant-login-to-debian-7-7-with-kerberos-nis-user

Comment: @DavidMackintosh: Nope :-(

Comment: @DavidMackintosh: IIRC, I *think* there's something called "nss" that is involved in looking up details on user's (basically, getpwent delegates to it), and I didn't have this set up. But I'm not sure if any of that is true, or correct — never had time to try.

Comment: @DavidMackintosh: Sorry for the comment spam, I just looked at your question. "This leads me to believe it is a problem with my  /etc/nsswitch.conf" <- that is what I meant above. I was thinking that was my problem too, but never got around to understanding that file or what I needed to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your SSH server configured for kerberos? E.g.

```
KerberosAuthentication yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UseDNS yes
```

From what I see above, SSH it is attempting to login with credentials rather than by presenting a kerberos ticket (that you can get by using kinit on the client side). Sure, as you pointed above, kinit works on your client, which is good. Could you post the SSH/SSHD debug logs?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was at -1; it is the answer for me.